# PHP Looping array from excel

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to get the data that I uploaded from excel using foreach and for loop, but the weird thing is when I upload excel file w/ 12 rows it successfully insert, but when I upload excel w/ 13 rows and up its only get the last row and I'm getting the error `Uninitialized Offset :8`.

this is the array when I uploaded excel w/ 12 rows.

```
array(12) 
{ 
[0]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(123) [2]=> string(5) "apple" [3]=> float(45) [4]=> string(2) "pc" [5]=> string(5) "A1011" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42110) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } 
[1]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(6) "grapes" [3]=> float(2) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1012" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } 
[2]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(6) "grapes" [3]=> float(20) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1016" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } 
[3]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(5) "chico" [3]=> float(7) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1012" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "ads" } } 
[4]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(125) [2]=> string(9) "pineapple" [3]=> float(8) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1013" [6]=> float(1102) [7]=> float(42112) [8]=> string(3) "ads" } } 
[5]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(123) [2]=> string(5) "apple" [3]=> float(45) [4]=> string(2) "pc" [5]=> string(5) "A1011" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42110) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } 
[6]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(6) "grapes" [3]=> float(2) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1012" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } 
[7]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(6) "grapes" [3]=> float(20) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1016" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } 
[8]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(5) "chico" [3]=> float(7) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1012" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "ads" } } 
[9]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(125) [2]=> string(9) "pineapple" [3]=> float(8) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1013" [6]=> float(1102) [7]=> float(42112) [8]=> string(3) "ads" } }
[10]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(123) [2]=> string(5) "apple" [3]=> float(45) [4]=> string(2) "pc" [5]=> string(5) "A1011" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42110) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } }
[11]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(6) "grapes" [3]=> float(2) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1012" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(4) "a1a1" } } }
```

this is when 13 rows it only get the last row.

```
array(1) 
{
[0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(6) "grapes" [3]=> float(2) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1012" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(4) "a1a1" } }
```

below is my code.

```
var_dump ($dataRow); 
        if (isset($dataRow)) {  
       echo '<pre>';
            foreach($dataRow as $key => $dataVal)   {
                foreach($dataVal as $key => $dataSume)  {
                    $fArray = $dataSume;

                    for($x=0; $x < 1; $x++ ){
                        $refs = strlen($fArray[0]);
                            $this->varOrder->addCount($fArray[0],$fArray[1],$fArray[2],$fArray[3],$fArray[4],$fArray[5],$fArray[6],$fArray[7],$fArray[8],$flag2);
                    }
                }
            }
        echo '</pre>';
         }
                $data['mode'] = 'Empty';
                $data['message'] = 'Data Successfully Uploaded!';
                $this->session->unset_userdata($dataRow);
                $this->session->unset_userdata('Count');
                $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
```

My question is why I'm only get the last row when I'm start inserting 13 rows and up, is this on my foreach or for loop syntax?

Comment: I don't understand your question fully. But, at least your for loop **for($x=0; $x < 1; $x++ ) {  }** is somehow strange. This means: initialise $x with 0 (zero); do the loop as long as $x is < 1 (zero or less than zero); at the end of the loop increment $x by 1. So,**the loop is performed just once!**

Comment: @hherger My question is why I'm only get the last row when I'm start inserting 13 rows and up, is this on my foreach or for loop syntax?

Comment: @hherger I already did that increment $x by one and stop when $x < 1.

Comment: I have added a commented solution. Please try and give feedback.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I created a *$dataRow* array similar to what your *var_dump* shows and tried it with your code: the same result as you say. Then I looked at the structure of *$dataRow* and your loops.

I'm sure your **foreach -> foreach -> for** construct does not accurately enough correspond to the structure of the **$dataRow**; there's the problem.
The  array: *$dataRow* is…

- an **array of arrays**.
- The subordinate arrays **contain exactly one item** (index=0); these are "dummy" arrays, which…
- contain a real **array of scalar entries**, i.e. the relevant data.

So, the structure is:

- $dataRow
- (Dummy) array, contains just one element
- array of data
- data item

You struggled probably with the "dummy" array. And you corrected this "dummy" level somehow with your one-pass *for(…)* loop, which in fact is not needed.

I tried it with (nearly) your data, 16 rows. It also works with any number of rows in the *$dataRow* array. There is a *foreach* loop for the outer-most array and the inner-most array. The dummy array in between is covered by the *foreach($dataVal[0]…)* construct.

### Code

```
<?php

$dataRow = array(
    array( array( "CC-00057", 1, "apple", 45, "pc", "A1011", 1101, 42110, "asd" ) ),
    array( array( "CC-00057", 2, "grapes", 2, "box", 5, "A1012", 1101, 42111, "asd" ) ),
    array( array( "CC-00057", 3, "grapes", 2, "box", 5, "A1012", 1101, 42111, "asd" ) ),
    array( array( "CC-00057", 4, "grapes", 2, "box", 5, "A1012", 1101, 42111, "asd" ) ),
    array( array( "CC-00057", 5, "grapes", 2, "box", 5, "A1012", 1101, 42111, "asd" ) ),
    array( array( "CC-00057", 6, "grapes", 2, "box", 5, "A1012", 1101, 42111, "asd" ) ),
    array( array( "CC-00057", 7, "grapes", 2, "box", 5, "A1012", 1101, 42111, "asd" ) ),
    array( array( "CC-00057", 8, "grapes", 2, "box", 5, "A1012", 1101, 42111, "asd" ) ),
    array( array( "CC-00057", 9, "grapes", 2, "box", 5, "A1012", 1101, 42111, "asd" ) ),
    array( array( "CC-00057", 10, "grapes", 2, "box", 5, "A1012", 1101, 42111, "asd" ) ),
    array( array( "CC-00057", 11, "grapes", 2, "box", 5, "A1012", 1101, 42111, "asd" ) ),
    array( array( "CC-00057", 12, "grapes", 2, "box", 5, "A1012", 1101, 42111, "asd" ) ),
    array( array( "CC-00057", 13, "grapes", 2, "box", 5, "A1012", 1101, 42111, "asd" ) ),
    array( array( "CC-00057", 14, "grapes", 2, "box", 5, "A1012", 1101, 42111, "asd" ) ),
    array( array( "CC-00057", 15, "grapes", 2, "box", 5, "A1012", 1101, 42111, "asd" ) ),
    array( array( "CC-00057", 16, "grapes", 2, "box", 5, "A1012", 1101, 42111, "asd" ) ),
    array( array( "CC-00057", 17, "grapes", 2, "box", 5, "A1012", 1101, 42111, "asd" ) ),
);

echo '<h2>The $dataRow Array</h2><pre>'; var_dump ($dataRow); echo '</pre>';
if (isset($dataRow)) {  
    echo '<h2>The Result</h2><pre>';
    // Outer-most array
    foreach($dataRow as $row => $dataVal) {
        // Data arrays are in $dataVal[0], the inner-most array
        // -> Display the data array
        $res = '';
        foreach($dataVal[0] as $key => $value) {
            $res .= ((empty($res)) ? '' : ', ') . "$key=$value";
        }
        echo "Row $row: " . $res . PHP_EOL;
    }
    echo '</pre>';
}

?>
```

Obviously, if the "dummy" array could have more than one entry, the nested *foreach* loops would look like this:

```
foreach($dataRow as $row => $dataVal) {
    foreach($dataVal as $data) {
        foreach($data as $key => $value) {
            // Process the the items in the data array
        }
    }
}
```

### Result

```
Row 0: 0=CC-00057, 1=1, 2=apple, 3=45, 4=pc, 5=A1011, 6=1101, 7=42110, 8=asd
Row 1: 0=CC-00057, 1=2, 2=grapes, 3=2, 4=box, 5=5, 6=A1012, 7=1101, 8=42111, 9=asd
Row 2: 0=CC-00057, 1=3, 2=grapes, 3=2, 4=box, 5=5, 6=A1012, 7=1101, 8=42111, 9=asd
Row 3: 0=CC-00057, 1=4, 2=grapes, 3=2, 4=box, 5=5, 6=A1012, 7=1101, 8=42111, 9=asd
Row 4: 0=CC-00057, 1=5, 2=grapes, 3=2, 4=box, 5=5, 6=A1012, 7=1101, 8=42111, 9=asd
Row 5: 0=CC-00057, 1=6, 2=grapes, 3=2, 4=box, 5=5, 6=A1012, 7=1101, 8=42111, 9=asd
Row 6: 0=CC-00057, 1=7, 2=grapes, 3=2, 4=box, 5=5, 6=A1012, 7=1101, 8=42111, 9=asd
Row 7: 0=CC-00057, 1=8, 2=grapes, 3=2, 4=box, 5=5, 6=A1012, 7=1101, 8=42111, 9=asd
Row 8: 0=CC-00057, 1=9, 2=grapes, 3=2, 4=box, 5=5, 6=A1012, 7=1101, 8=42111, 9=asd
Row 9: 0=CC-00057, 1=10, 2=grapes, 3=2, 4=box, 5=5, 6=A1012, 7=1101, 8=42111, 9=asd
Row 10: 0=CC-00057, 1=11, 2=grapes, 3=2, 4=box, 5=5, 6=A1012, 7=1101, 8=42111, 9=asd
Row 11: 0=CC-00057, 1=12, 2=grapes, 3=2, 4=box, 5=5, 6=A1012, 7=1101, 8=42111, 9=asd
Row 12: 0=CC-00057, 1=13, 2=grapes, 3=2, 4=box, 5=5, 6=A1012, 7=1101, 8=42111, 9=asd
Row 13: 0=CC-00057, 1=14, 2=grapes, 3=2, 4=box, 5=5, 6=A1012, 7=1101, 8=42111, 9=asd
Row 14: 0=CC-00057, 1=15, 2=grapes, 3=2, 4=box, 5=5, 6=A1012, 7=1101, 8=42111, 9=asd
Row 15: 0=CC-00057, 1=16, 2=grapes, 3=2, 4=box, 5=5, 6=A1012, 7=1101, 8=42111, 9=asd
Row 16: 0=CC-00057, 1=17, 2=grapes, 3=2, 4=box, 5=5, 6=A1012, 7=1101, 8=42111, 9=asd
```