# PHP insert data from excel file - Loop error

Tags: php, excel, codeigniter

I'm trying to get the data that I uploaded from excel using foreach and for loop, but the weird thing is when I upload excel file w/ 12 rows it successfully inserted, but when I upload excel w/ 13 rows and up its only get the last row and I'm getting the error `Uninitialized Offset :8.`

this is the array when I uploaded excel w/ 12 rows.

```
array(12) 
{ 
[0]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(123) [2]=> string(5) "apple" [3]=> float(45) [4]=> string(2) "pc" [5]=> string(5) "A1011" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42110) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } 
[1]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(6) "grapes" [3]=> float(2) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1012" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } 
[2]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(6) "grapes" [3]=> float(20) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1016" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } 
[3]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(5) "chico" [3]=> float(7) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1012" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "ads" } } 
[4]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(125) [2]=> string(9) "pineapple" [3]=> float(8) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1013" [6]=> float(1102) [7]=> float(42112) [8]=> string(3) "ads" } } 
[5]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(123) [2]=> string(5) "apple" [3]=> float(45) [4]=> string(2) "pc" [5]=> string(5) "A1011" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42110) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } 
[6]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(6) "grapes" [3]=> float(2) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1012" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } 
[7]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(6) "grapes" [3]=> float(20) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1016" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } } 
[8]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(5) "chico" [3]=> float(7) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1012" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(3) "ads" } } 
[9]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(125) [2]=> string(9) "pineapple" [3]=> float(8) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1013" [6]=> float(1102) [7]=> float(42112) [8]=> string(3) "ads" } }
[10]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(123) [2]=> string(5) "apple" [3]=> float(45) [4]=> string(2) "pc" [5]=> string(5) "A1011" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42110) [8]=> string(3) "asd" } }
[11]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(6) "grapes" [3]=> float(2) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1012" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(4) "a1a1" } } }
```

this is when 13 rows it only get the last row.

```
 array(1) 
    {
    [0]=> array(9) { [0]=> string(8) "CC-00057" [1]=> float(124) [2]=> string(6) "grapes" [3]=> float(2) [4]=> string(3) "box" [5]=> string(5) "A1012" [6]=> float(1101) [7]=> float(42111) [8]=> string(4) "a1a1" } }
```

below is my code.

```
var_dump ($dataRow); 
        if (isset($dataRow)) {  
       echo '<pre>';
            foreach($dataRow as $key => $dataVal)   {
                foreach($dataVal as $key => $dataSume)  {
                    $fArray = $dataSume;

                    for($x=0; $x < 1; $x++ ){
                        $refs = strlen($fArray[0]);
                            $this->varOrder->addCount($fArray[0],$fArray[1],$fArray[2],$fArray[3],$fArray[4],$fArray[5],$fArray[6],$fArray[7],$fArray[8],$flag2);
                    }
                }
            }
        echo '</pre>';
         }
                $data['mode'] = 'Empty';
                $data['message'] = 'Data Successfully Uploaded!';
                $this->session->unset_userdata($dataRow);
                $this->session->unset_userdata('Count');
                $this->load->view('home_view', $data);
```

My question is why I'm only get the last row when I'm start inserting 13 rows and up, is this on my foreach or for loop syntax?

Comment: Better show us code which generates contents of `$dataRow`

Comment: Did you tried debugging your code? You have tree for loops nested. It will be very hard to guess anything. But I think it might be a problem with your implementation. 

Try at least to upload some sample data. 

Like a declared array. Instead of pasting the var_dump result.

Comment: @ u_mulder alreay posted above

Comment: @RicardoSilva declared array?

Comment: @RicardoSilva i need to loop it trice to get the exact value in the array as what showed above.

Comment: I meant the data itself, a simple sql like a table with the values will make give a better picture than a var_dump output.

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34992898/php-looping-array-from-excel